# UIPickerView scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Здравствуйте!

Такая проблема, есть `UIPickerView`, на центральной строке (та строка, что выделена), добавлена кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит `event`, но если начинать скроллить `UIPickerView` с кнопки, то скроллинг не работает. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Убрал кнопку и добавил `UITapGestureRecognizer`. [Ссылка на ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25719326/608343).

Добавляем `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToSelect = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(tappedToSelectRow:)];
tapToSelect.delegate = self;
[self.pickerView addGestureRecognizer:tapToSelect];
```

Обрабатываем нажатие:

```
#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)tappedToSelectRow:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    if (tapRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGFloat rowHeight = [self.pickerView rowSizeForComponent:0].height;
        CGRect selectedRowFrame = CGRectInset(self.pickerView.bounds, 0.0, (CGRectGetHeight(self.pickerView.frame) - rowHeight) / 2.0 );
        BOOL userTappedOnSelectedRow = (CGRectContainsPoint(selectedRowFrame, [tapRecognizer locationInView:self.pickerView]));
        if (userTappedOnSelectedRow) {
            // Тут выполняем нужное действие
        }
    }
}
```

И не забываем про:

```
#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @D-side исправил. Спасибо!